Customed quantum channel definition with Qiskit
According to this manual, the noise models can be implemente to a specific set of gates given by the user.
However, is there a way to implement a noise source acting at a specified time, rather than associating it to a gate?

This is just a thought and I have not tested this but there is a way to achieve what you want. Make a quantum circuit (call it qc1) with 10 Hadamard gates (for example) on which you would like to apply the noise, then add noise model to these gates. Next, construct another quantum circuit (call it qc2) with the rest of the gates and components. Now compose qc1 on qc2. I think by doing this you can only apply noise on 10 Hadamard gates only.

You can model a noisy gate as the composition of a noise channel, followed by the unitary action of the gate itself.
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.extensions import IGate
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel, errors

i_gate = IGate(label="depolarizing")
i_error = errors.depolarizing_error(0.1, 1)

noise_model = NoiseModel()
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(i_error, i_gate.label)

qc = qk.QuantumCircuit(1) 

qc.append(i_gate,[0])
qc.h([0])
qc.draw()


   ┌───┐┌───┐
q: ┤ I ├┤ H ├
   └───┘└───┘

This is not different from associating the noise directly to the gate.
I personally prefer the unitary and the noise to be separated. Because it is easy to define and place channels.
